# Sending messages from Server to Socket by a specified user ID

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, client-server

I'm new to Java and i'm trying to figure out some problems..

I want to be able to send a message from a server to a client by specifing his ID.
I thought about it and i figured that it would be a good idea if i would create a PrintWriter for each client that connects and put it in a PrintWriter array, however this does not seem to work, hope you guys can/will help me.

Some of the method names are in my mother language hope that isn't a problem.

```
package homeControl;

import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Server {
    String sporocilo = null;
    int id = 0;
    ServerHandler handler = new ServerHandler();

    public void sprejmiPovezavo() {
        try {
            ServerSocket svrSock = new ServerSocket(5000);
            Socket klientSocket = svrSock.accept();

            new Thread(new ServerHandler(klientSocket));
        } catch(IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Server svr = new Server();
        svr.sprejmiPovezavo();
    }
}
```

Server Handler Code:

```
package homeControl;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class ServerHandler implements Runnable {
Socket klientSocket;
static int userCounter = 0;
static int selectedId = 0;
BufferedReader reader;
PrintWriter writer;
PrintWriter[] writerHolder = new PrintWriter[10];

outputHelper out = new outputHelper();  

public ServerHandler(Socket klientSocket) throws IOException {
    userCounter++;
    this.klientSocket = klientSocket;
    writer = new PrintWriter(this.klientSocket.getOutputStream());
    writerHolder[userCounter] = writer;

    InputStreamReader inReader = new InputStreamReader(this.klientSocket.getInputStream());
    reader = new BufferedReader(inReader);

    out.frameOutput(this.klientSocket.getInetAddress().toString(), "Server sprejel povezavo:");

    selectedId = userCounter;
    posljiSporocilo("wassup");
}

public ServerHandler() {
    // Do not launch the main Constructor
}

public void run(){
    String inMessage = null;
    try{
        while((inMessage = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("Server Sprejel: " + inMessage);
        }
    } catch(IOException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }   
}

public  void selectId(int id){
    selectedId = id;
}

public void posljiSporocilo(String sporocilo){
    writerHolder[selectedId].println(sporocilo + "\n");
    writerHolder[selectedId].flush();
}
}
```

Comment: Tell us what exactly doesn't work as expected?

Comment: There's nothing inherintly wrong with what you are trying to do.  I would put it in a hash, but an array can work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you have written, only one client will be able to connect to the server.
The following change allows you to accept multiple clients. The server accepts and serves a connection request and then it continues to accept others.

```
ServerSocket svrSock;
try{
    svrSock = new ServerSocket(5000);
} catch(IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.exit(-1);
}
while(true){
   try {
        Socket klientSocket = svrSock.accept();
        new Thread(new ServerHandler(klientSocket));
   } catch(IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Modestino, it worked :)